# Meteor: render template inside a template on click

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a Meteor app that has a template loaded.
Inside that template I have a button.
When the button is clicked, I want the app to render or switch to another template which also happens to be a modal.

I can't figure out how to render another template from the click event function.

Any ideas? Here is my code below.

**search.html**

```
<template name='search'>

    <button class='btn btn-primary' id='showModalButton'>Show Modal</button>

</template>

<template name='searchCustomer'>

    <!-- set up the modal to start hidden and fade in and out -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
          <!-- dialog body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
              My modal body
          <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

**search.js**

```
Template.search.onRendered(function() {
    'click #showModalButton': {
       // WHAT DO I DO HERE TO RENDER OR CALL THE 
       // SEARCHCUSTOMER TEMPLATE WITH THE MODAL?
    }

});

Template.searchCustomer.onRendered(function() {

    $("#myModal").on("show", function() {    
          $("#myModal a.btn").on("click", function(e) {
              $("#myModal").modal('hide');
          });
      });

      $("#myModal").on("hide", function() {    
          $("#myModal a.btn").off("click");
      });

      $("#myModal").on("hidden", function() {  
          $("#myModal").remove();
      });

      $("#myModal").modal({                    
        "backdrop"  : "static",
        "keyboard"  : true,
        "show"      : true   // show the modal immediately                  
      });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this, but I believe you can use a template helper and a Session variable to accomplish this.

```
<body>
  {{> search }}
  {{#if showModal }}
    {{> searchCustomer }}
  {{/if}}
</body>
```

and then in your js file...

```
Template.search.helpers({
    'showModal': function(){
        return Session.get('showModal');
    }
    'click #showModalButton': function(){
        Session.set('showModal', true);
    }
);
```

The searchCustomer template will only render when the 'showModal' Session variable is true.